# What does that error mean in Azure Data factory?

Tags: azure, copy, azure-pipelines

What I want to do is, I have 6 tables in Azure Warehouse and I have 2 tables in Azure database and I want to execute a pipeline which will copy data from one table SalesLT.ProductCategory which is at Warehouse to dbo.DimProductCategory which is at Database.

And I am getting the error like this.

{ "errorCode": "2200", "message": "ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed. Please search error to get more details.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__DimProdu__3224ECEE2FD4E7AD'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.DimProductCategory'. The duplicate key value is (1).\r\nThe statement has been terminated.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=2627,Class=14,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=14,Number=2627,State=1,Message=Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__DimProdu__3224ECEE2FD4E7AD'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.DimProductCategory'. The duplicate key value is (1).,},{Class=0,Number=3621,State=0,Message=The statement has been terminated.,},],'", "failureType": "UserError", "target": "productcategory", "details": [] }

Here is the structure of the DimProductCategory Table..

```
create table DimProductCategory
(
ProductCategoryID int not null primary key,
name nvarchar(max)
)
```

I have tried deleting primary key from dimProductCategory table but still got the same error.